# Compare two tables with cartesian coordinates and compute difference

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables containing cartesian coordinates of specified named points.

Table1 has points named like `PX_<number>` or `P_<number>`. Table2 has points with only numbers. The order of the points may be random and there may be situation that there will be lack of one or more points in Table1 or Table2.

[image]

I would like to compare these two tables by merging them into third table which will contain the paired points and calculated (absolute) distance of every coordinate.

Also it should colorize cells where the difference is greater than desired by the user by the user in certain cell (e.g. 0,1). Example:

[image]

I wanted to do it via Power Query, but I will need to select tables every time the points will change (they will be pasted from outside source). So I decided to make it via VBA macro, while coloring cells via conditional formatting.

I have problem with matching points from two tables. So I decided to remove unnecessary prefixes (`PX_` or `P_`) from points with following script in VBA  which may help to sort and pair them. But still, how can I pair and list them respectively taking into account potential lack of points in Table1 or Table2?

```
Private Sub Filter_points_Click()
    Dim searchRow As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim allPoints As Range
    
'   Find lastRow in column B
    Set searchRow = Range("B3:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    lastRow = searchRow.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

'   Set Range of existing points
    Set allPoints = Range("B3:B" & lastRow)
    
'   Replace P_ & PX_
    allPoints.Replace What:="P_", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    
    allPoints.Replace What:="PX_", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can solve it without VBA.
Sorry, I use HUN version of Excel, so I just try to guess the English functions properly.

1. Add a column to the left of each table, this will be the "key" to the "point" values.
   They will be in the same format in both T1 and T2, so you can easily VLOOKUP them to find matches.
   Function sg like this in the cells:

in A3 (for T1):

```
= "L" & MID(B3,TEXT.FIND("_",B3)+1,100)
```

in A10 (for T2):

```
="L" & B10
```

So the result table (T1-T2) will contain the following:
in C15:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A10,$A$3:$E$5,4,0)-C10,"N.A")
```

The B column in 3rd table (B15..17) just simple links to T2 (A10..A12)

The result will look like this (with smaller T1 and T2 tables):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0igB.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer and idea. Looking at your screen you had probably small typo with col_index. After small fixes is looks to work hovewer only when T2 contains points that are missing in T1. What in case when T1 has points unavailable in T2? In your case L5 from row 3? It should be listed too.

Comment: wow, col_index was mistyped, great catch :) to solve "L5" issue, you need to add rows to "T1-T2" table, where B cells link to T1 table accordingly, and in the rest of the table make similar IFERROR (VLOOKUP... functions. In this way you will get duplicated rows, but you can avoid them if add an IF(COUNTIF... combination in B column (so you can have "" in a B cell if the point ID already occurs in B15-B17). This short comment is not the proper way to describe it to you in depth, but I'm sure you will find it out. :)

Comment: Maybe: https://excelchamps.com/blog/highlight-duplicate-values-vba/

Comment: Thanks for link @ASH. Unfortunately it compares just single columns, I need to compare them together by point name because different points can have the same single coordinate.

Comment: @Apafey Sadly I can't get it to work :(. Every cell should have addittional condition to avoid duplicates, not just link to T2, then T1 because amount of pointsin both tables may vary.

Additionally xyz cells should have rules to calculate difference between points if certain point in "T1-T2" is from T1, not T2 so rules  "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP...)" in xyz cells should be also modified. Could you explain how to do it more thoroughly?